# ReactWrapper::state() can only be called on class components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I recently converted my class component to a functional component using React Hooks and now some of my tests are failing. The error I get is:

```
ReactWrapper::state() can only be called on class components
```

and I think it's because in my test I use `.state`. Is there an alternative to this so my tests will pass now that I no longer have a class component?

```
it('sets field state isInputActive to true onFocus', () => {
    const component = mount(<PinInput pin="123" onChange={() => {}} />);

    expect(component.childAt(0).state('isInputActive')).toEqual(false);
    component.find('.parental-pin__input-entry').simulate('click');
    expect(component.childAt(0).state('isInputActive')).toEqual(true);
  });
```

Comment: You can't directly access the state outside the component, proceed from this fact. You need to affect it indirectly and assert change it causes on the component. Enzyme is inefficient for this. Check how things are done in React Testing Library.

Comment: Do you think I should remove the test compeltely?

Comment: I think it should be rewritten to assert DOM or other effects that component state causes.

Comment: Show the code under test